# sqlalchemy add label to static string in select

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

this is my query:

```
select 'somestring' as my_col_name
from my_table
```

when using sql alchemy:

```
query = db.session.query(
  'somestring'.label('my_col_name'))
)
```

but I get this error:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'label'
```

how can I add a label on sqlalchemy to a static string field?
(I need it for some unions I do after)

Answer (score 4):

use `literal_column`

```
query = db.session.query(
  literal_column("'somestring'").label('my_col_name'))
)
```

Comment: `'somestring' as my_col_name` is not the same as `literal_column('somestring').label('my_col_name'))`, the latter produces `somestring as my_col_name`, i.e. tries to select from a *column* called `somestring`. If you want to pass a literal, then use just that: `sqlalchemy.literal`.

Comment: correct, I fixed it - wrapped with `"` quotes